# Display turning off in windows 10 when fullscreen video is paused for 15mn on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep, external-display

My displays shut down by themselves when I leave a video paused in fullscreen on my second monitor, even though every option is set to "Never" put them to sleep.

First I want to say that I've already turned off every power saving option to turn off the display or putting the computer to sleep when inactive, even the most obscure ones.
As you can see:

My Power and Sleep options:

[image: My Power and Sleep options]

My Power settings:

[image: My Power settings]

My Power Plan:

[image: My Power Plan]

My Power Plan's settings (main, system unattended, multimedia):

[image: My Power Plan's settings 1]

[image: My Power Plan's settings 2 ("system unattended")]

[image: My Power Plan's settings 3 (Multimedia settings)]

And yet, when I leave a video paused on my second monitor for more than 10 or 15 minutes the displays shut off by themselves. Which sucks especially because my 2nd monitor, an "IIYAMA GB2888UHSU-B1 G-MASTER Gold" doesn't wake up by itself when I jiggle the mouse. That's a separate issue I think because I've set it at 60Hz and that frequency doesn't wake the monitor from power saving mode, I have to set it at 30Hz for it to wake up then to 60Hz (I use a batch file with dc64cmd* so it's not much of a bother to wake it up but I would like for it not to sleep at all in the first place!).

The issue is why it's going to sleep in the first place!

The app I use to watch videos is Media Player Classic Black Edition but I scoured its settings and there is nothing in there to shut off the display, so I've no idea where it's coming from.

EDIT: Like a rookie I completly forgot my specs! Sorry guys, too much work these days.
So it's a laptop, an MSI GP76 LEOPARD 11UG-023FR, Windows 10 Family edition, NVIDIA® GPU GeForce RTX™ 3070 Mobile 8Gb GDDR6, RAM 16Gb , 1x M.2 SSD, screen 17.3" Full HD (1920 x 1080), 240 Hz.
The second monitor is plugged in HDMI 2.0, it's a G-MASTER GB2888UHSU-B1 GOLD PHOENIX, cf https://iiyama.com/gl_en/products/g-master-gb2888uhsu-b1/
They say "HDMI1: max. 3840 x 2160 @60Hz" but like I said with that rate the computer doesn't wake up from power saving mode.

- For your edification here is how I wake it up (if someone has the same problem with an IIYAMA not waking up in 60Hz, they can download dc64cmd, add it to windows path variable and use this in a batch file):

```
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -secondary -width=3840 -height=2160 -depth=32 -refresh=30 -fixedoutput=default
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -secondary -width=3840 -height=2160 -depth=32 -refresh=max -fixedoutput=default
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -left
dc64cmd -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -ty=-1080 -apply
```

I first wake it up by setting the refresh rate at 30Hz then and only then do I set it to its max value, which is 60Hz.

Comment: The huge images with lots of white make this rather hard to scroll through, could you crop them down to something more manageable?

Comment: Ok. Cropped the two power options screenshots.